# Concat all strings from dictionary (values) using LINQ without external variable

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, concatenation

Having dictionary where key can be anything (e.g. int) and values is some text I want to output.

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

dict.Add(1, "This is the first line.");
dict.Add(2, "This is the second line.");
dict.Add(3, "This is the third line.");
```

To get output:

```
string lResult = dict. ... //there should go the LINQ query
Console.WriteLine(lResult);
```

**Output:**

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
This is the third line.
```

**Q: Is it possible to concatenate the lines from `Dictionary` to have them as one string without using external variable?**

---

I tried approach using some `Select/SelectMany/Zip` solutions, but I cannot figure how to pass the value from 1 LINQ call to other without using external variable.

Another idea is to `Select` values, put them to the List and then Concatenate (again using external variable). Like:

```
string tmp = "";
dict.Select(a => a.Value).ToList().ForEach(b => tmp += b);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't use LINQ to concat strings. This can become [very expenisve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm). Use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join) innstead:

```
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dict.Values);
```

---

However, this does not guarantee the correct order, because a `Dictionary<>` is not sorted. To sort the output by the `Key`s you can do this:

```
string sorted = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                     dict.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).Select(kvp => kvp.Value));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dict.Values)
```

Note however, that [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx) states the values will be retrieved in an unspecified order.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using StringBuilder if you want to use LINQ. Otherwise the performance will suffer too much:

```
string lResult = dict.Values.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (a, b) => a.Append(b)).ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Appending `string` in a *loop*

```
ForEach(b => tmp += b)
```

is an *antipattern*; you should use `StringBuilder`. In case you *have to use* `Linq` (not `string.Join` which is specially designed for it):

```
  dict.Add(1, "This is the first line.");
  dict.Add(2, "This is the second line.");
  dict.Add(3, "This is the third line.");

  string result = dict
    .OrderBy(pair => pair.Key)
    .Aggregate((StringBuilder) null, 
               (sb, pair) => (sb == null 
                  ? new StringBuilder() 
                  : sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)).Append(pair.Value))
    .ToString();
```